# ipad 1 GSM 4.3.3 firmware

Tags: ipad, ios

I have an Ipad 1 GSM (it takes a 3g sim) and i've been looking for the IOS 4.3.3 firmware but cannot find it anywhere online.

i found this

iPad1,1_4.3.3_8J3_Restore.ipsw

but it does not work. Itunes says "The ipad "main ipad" could not be restored. this device isn't eligible for the requested build."

So i'm guessing that ipsw is for wifi only devices. Where do i find gsm version then?

Answer (score 2):

Try this website: http://www.felixbruns.de/iPod/firmware/

But it might not work because 4.3.5 is out. iPad 1 wifi and 3g firmware are the same.

Comment: Apple will have stopped signing the 4.3.3 release, hence the slightly cryptic "not eligible" message...

Answer (score 1):

[Here's a list](http://iclarified.com/entry/index.php?enid=8500) of every firmware version that's ever been released for iPads with links to download them.

You should ideally be installing [v4.3.5](http://appldnld.apple.com/iPhone4/041-1957.20110721.6UHaN/iPad1,1_4.3.5_8L1_Restore.ipsw) (Direct Download Link) which came out a few days ago. Hold down the Alt/Option key to get a browse menu and select the file.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot restore to 4.3.3, because Apple does not allow restoring devices to old iOS versions. A deep technical explanation is found on the [Caching Apple's Signature Server](http://www.saurik.com/id/12) article by Saurik.

The short version is that if you want to retain your ability to restore to old versions of iOS, you should save signatures for your device with either Cydia (this means jailbreaking) or [TinyUmbrella](http://thefirmwareumbrella.blogspot.com/) when they are available and use them later in the restore process.